# How can i draw a image on the screen with random porpotions?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I want to show a image of a donut on the screen, but I want it to be random how big it is and how big the hole in the donut is. Is There Any easy way to do this?

I Cant just scale or descale a image of a donut because i want the hole to have different sizes also.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Take an image of a donut without a hole and scale it randomly. 2. Take an image of just the hole of the donut, scale it randomly. 3. Display the hole on top of the donut.

Comment: @Ruzihm I was thinking exactly in the same approach but I think one would have to make the "hole" image also somehow a mask on the "donut" image in order to make it really transparent. E.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-cut-out-part-of-ui.345708/

Comment: @derHugo good point. I would refer OP to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html . They can have the without-hole donut set to `Not Visible Under Mask` and put a circular mask on top with the same size of the hole.

Comment: @Ruzihm Top ;) make it an answer

Comment: @derHugo done ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by following these  steps:

- Create a game object that only contains a `Sorting Group`.
- As child objects of that object create the following:

  1. Make a `Sprite Renderer` of a donut without a hole. Scale it randomly. Set its `Mask Interaction` to `Not Visible Under Mask`
  2. Make a `Sprite Renderer` of the hole of a donut. Scale it randomly. Make sure its `Mask Interaction` is set to `None`.
  3. Make a [Sprite Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html) that has the same shape as the hole in step 2, and scale it to be the same size as the hole in part 2.
  4. Layer these pieces top to bottom like: Donut Hole (step 2), Sprite Mask (step 3), Donut-without-hole (step 1)

At the end it should look like

```
- Object with SortingGroup
  - Donut Hole Sprite (Mask Interaction: None)
  - Sprite Mask
  - Donut-without-Hole Sprite (Mask Interaction: Not Visible Under Mask)
```

Putting the donut sprites together inside the SortingGroup parent allows you to have many donuts without the masks interfering with other donuts.